# Post CSS parse error on calc() of CSS variables with several default values

Tags: css, nuxt.js, postcss, css-variables, postcss-loader

I'm running a Nuxt.JS project with Post CSS and get the following error while generating the project's static version:

```
JisonParserError: Parse error on line 1:
calc(100% / 12) * var(--cols-md, var(--cols-sm, var(--cols, (12))))
-----------------------------------------------------------------^
```

The CSS snippet **that fails** – but is correct markup according to W3C CSS Validator – looks like this:

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .c-col {
    width: calc(calc(100% / 12) * var(--cols-md, var(--cols-sm, var(--cols, 12))));
  }
}
```

The strange thing is that it starts to fail after adding the third fallback. Because this snippet, which is further up in the document, **is parsed correctly**.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .c-col {
    width: calc(calc(100% / 12) * var(--cols-sm, var(--cols, 12)));
  }
}
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: You can post the answer below, it is fine to accept your own answer. :)

Comment: Thanks! I posted it and accept it as soon as it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**found an answer:** it seems to be a bug: https://github.com/postcss/postcss-calc/issues/104 somone also posted a workaround: temporarily save a chunk of variables into another one to use it as an intermediary.